# my server sending mails without me sending it

Tags: linux, centos, email

last night i see many mail undelivery messages but i have not send any messages.
I have only one site live on it.

is there any way to find out more details about it. i don't know where to start

these are reject logs from exim

```
2013-03-01 03:27:31 H=114-42-128-4.dynamic.hinet.net (125.214.75.163) [114.42.128.4]:4227 rejected MAIL <z2007tw@yahoo.com.tw>: Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.3)
2013-03-01 05:13:10 H=(gyrvpwe.com) [27.41.134.95]:4702 F=<gpgjouczsr@gmail.com> rejected RCPT <vqvgb8924@yahoo.com.tw>: Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client, or login to the IMAP/POP3 server before sending your message.  (gyrvpwe.com) [27.41.134.95]:4702 is not permitted to relay through this server without authentication.
2013-03-01 09:37:20 courier_plain authenticator failed for localhost [127.0.0.1]:53728: 435 Unable to authenticate at present (set_id=__cpanel__service__auth__exim__DTGm12zHmcIhHGj1OI5GgfzrB5j7sk5UEyxNaYj7UqGFGstIMLklIjsIMYvPpAIt): failed to connect to socket /var/spool/authdaemon/socket: Connection refused inside "and{...}" condition
```

these were the few logs from

/var/log/messages

```
Mar  1 05:13:03 cpanel named[1442]: network unreachable resolving 'ns4.apnic.net/A/IN': 2001:dc0:4001:1:0:1836:0:140#53
Mar  1 05:13:04 cpanel named[1442]: network unreachable resolving 'tinnie.apnic.net/AAAA/IN': 2001:dc0:2001:0:4608::25#53
Mar  1 05:13:08 cpanel named[1442]: network unreachable resolving 'yahoo.com.tw/MX/IN': 2001:b000:168::1:c:10#53
Mar  1 05:57:45 cpanel named[1442]: network unreachable resolving 'colorado.edu/NS/IN': 2001:503:cc2c::2:36#53
Mar  1 06:15:02 cpanel named[1442]: network unreachable resolving 'httpupdate.cpanel.net/A/IN': 2001:503:a83e::2:30#53
Mar  1 06:15:02 cpanel named[1442]: network unreachable resolving 'httpupdate.cpanel.net/A/IN': 2001:503:231d::2:30#53
Mar  1 06:15:02 cpanel named[1442]: network unreachable resolving 'httpupdate.cpanel.net/A/IN': 2620:0:28a0:1528::3:1#53
Mar  1 06:27:51 cpanel named[1442]: network unreachable resolving 'akamai.com/NS/IN': 2600:1406:1b::64#53
Mar  1 07:28:03 cpanel named[1442]: network unreachable resolving 'mit.edu/NS/IN': 2001:503:cc2c::2:36#53
Mar  1 08:18:15 cpanel named[1442]: network unreachable resolving 'comcast.net/NS/IN': 2001:558:fe23:8:69:252:250:103#53
Mar  1 08:18:19 cpanel named[1442]: network unreachable resolving 'comcast.net/NS/IN': 2001:558:100a:5:68:87:68:244#53
Mar  1 08:18:19 cpanel named[1442]: network unreachable resolving 'comcast.net/NS/IN': 2001:558:100e:5:68:87:72:244#53
Mar  1 08:34:46 cpanel named[1442]: network unreachable resolving 'ns1.my.smartdns.net.au/A/IN': 2001:500:856e::6:34#53
Mar  1 08:34:47 cpanel named[1442]: network unreachable resolving 'hotmail.com/MX/IN': 2a01:111:2005::1:1#53
Mar  1 08:34:47 cpanel named[1442]: network unreachable resolving 'hotmail.com/MX/IN': 2a01:111:2006:6::1:1#53
Mar  1 08:34:47 cpanel named[1442]: network unreachable resolving 'clearfieldjeffersonredcross.org/MX/IN': 2001:500:f::1#53
Mar  1 08:34:47 cpanel named[1442]: network unreachable resolving 'clearfieldjeffersonredcross.org/MX/IN': 2001:500:b::1#53
Mar  1 08:34:47 cpanel named[1442]: network unreachable resolving 'msn.com/MX/IN': 2a01:111:2020::1:1#53
```

Comment: to see your sendmail config <code>cat /etc/mail/sendmail.mc</code>

Comment: @tiberious726 - He said he's running exim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has the look that you're either an open SMTP relay or, more likely, you've got software running on the server that is trying to send spam. If I had to guess, I'd suspect that your machine has been compromised.

I'd say you're in for restoring from known-clean backups or rebuilding the machine from the ground up.

Comment: how can i check that i have open smtp relay

Comment: which log files , i can check to see what could have happened

Comment: There's some discussion on Server Fault about detecting open relays: http://serverfault.com/questions/358695/how-to-find-out-that-smtp-server-is-in-open-relay  It sounds like you're above your level of expertise, though, and you'd probably better get some help from someone more experienced. Incident response, assuming you have been compromised, isn't something you can just be talked through.